# 404 Page Not Found url - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I downloaded codeigniter 3. 
Now,I would like to load a simple view, but I get this message :

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /Mobile/Vitrinsaz/Pannel/cp/auth/login was not found
>   on this server.

http://www.vitrinsaz1.ir/Mobile/Vitrinsaz/Pannel/cp/auth/login

```
/controllers
       /cp
           /auth
```

---

### auth.php:

```
<?php

class auth extends baseController
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function login( $msg = '' ){

        //$this->mustnot_be_logged();
        $this->load->view('login'  , '');
    }
}


/views
       /cp
           /login.blade.php
```

What did I do wrong?

**updated**

My `.htaccess` file in `/public_html/Mobile/Vitrinsaz/Pannel`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>



RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.vitrinsaz1.ir
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.vitrinsaz1.ir%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Read this http://w3code.in/2015/10/codeigniter-installation-beginner-guide/ and http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-insert-and-select-data-from-database-in-codeigniter-beginner-guide/

Answer (score 1):

Your class name shud start from capital letter

```
<?php

class Auth extends baseController
      ^
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function login( $msg = '' ){

        //$this->mustnot_be_logged();
        $this->load->view('login'  , '');
    }
}
```

And if you are using codeigniter3 your file name also should start with capital letter

```
Auth.php
```

Also if you are accessing without `index.php`, you sholud add `.htaccess`.

Also make sure that the folder names you are using is correct(without any spelling mistakes)

Comment: I changed name class to uppercase : `http://www.vitrinsaz1.ir/Mobile/Vitrinsaz/Pannel/cp/Auth/login`. but it shows 404 error.

Comment: no need to change in url. only in controller calss name.

Comment: have you added `.htaccess` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93281/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-s-m-emamian).